# How to access a windows shadow copy from WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, volume-shadow-copy, borg-backup

My aim is to use BorgBackup to back up a Windows 11 Pro machine. BorgBackup (v1.2.0) works fine within WSL (using Ubuntu 22.04) when the folder to back up is, e.g. `/mnt/c` it can back up the host. The backup completes, but it skips open files, and it's an inconsistent state, which is expected when just copying a running system.
That's why I created a shadow copy before on Windows (`wmic shadowcopy call create Volume=c:\`) which creates a volume like that `\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy273` which I mount to c:\shadow (`mklink /D c:\shadow \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy273\`)
My plan was to back up `/mnt/c/shadow` in WSL, but unfortunately the link is inaccessible.

```
# shadow-directory shows up, but with error
$ ls -l /mnt/c/shadow
ls: cannot read symbolic link '/mnt/c/shadow': Input/output error
lrwxrwxrwx 1 steffen steffen 0 Oct  4 16:29 /mnt/c/shadow

# shadow-directory is inaccessible
$ cd /mnt/c/shadow
-bash: cd: /mnt/c/shadow: Input/output error
```

Is there any possibility to access `\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy273\` with WSL?

I already tried `subst` but a "substed" drive doesn't show up in WSL.

Copying the content from the shadow copy to an accessible folder could be done, but in my case would be too time-consuming and requires too much extra space.